# What is the proper way to update a particular column in nestjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, nestjs

I want to save token generated into the user's confirmed email column. The token is part of the confirmation link that will be sent to the user so that when the user clicks on the link I can check if it matches, then updates it to "activated".

Now the problem is I can't figure out how to save it in the ConfirmEmailLink method .

```
   async register(createDTO: CreateUserDto) {
        const { email } = createDTO;
        const user = await this.userModel.findOne({ email })
        if (user) {
            throw new HttpException('User already exists', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        const createdUser = new this.userModel(createDTO);
        var newUser = await createdUser.save();


        await SendEmail(createDTO.email, await **this.ConfirmEmailLink(createdUser._id)**, createDTO.email);

        return this.sanitizeUser(createdUser);
        //return null;

    }
```

In the above code there is ConfirmEmailLink that is a parameter to SendEmail method

```
 async ConfirmEmailLink(userId: string) {
        const id = v4();
        var payload = { userId: userId };
        var secret = process.env.JWT_SIMPLE_TOKEN;
        var token = jwt.encode(payload, secret);
        console.log("This is uuid", userId);

        var link = `${process.env.HOST}/user/confirm/${token}/${id}`;

        let user = await this.userModel.findById(userId);

        if (!user) {
            throw new HttpException("Registration not complete, try again or contact admin", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

       **//This is where the problem is, I want to save the token in ConfirmEmail column** 
        await this.userModel.updateOne({confirmEmail: token});


        return link;

    }
```

I will appreciate your suggestions or if there is a better way to do this
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`updateOne` needs 2 parameters, a filter to identify which document to modify, and a update indicating what to do.

```
.updateOnde({"_id":userId},{"$set":{"confirmEmail": token}})
```